# Filter an ObservableCollection of DirectoryInfo with LINQ

Tags: c#, mvvm, treeview, directoryinfo

I'm using MVVM to populate a TreeView with a DirectoryInfo and all its sub-directories and files.

I then want to search through the treeview with LINQ .where() but I'm only searching the top directories and not the files.

**I'm creating the treeview/DirectoryInfo with a recursive method:**

```
  public class ItemProvider
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Item> GetItems(string path)
        {
            var items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

            if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                

                var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);

                foreach (var directory in dirInfo.EnumerateDirectories())
                {
                    var item = new DirectoryItem
                    {
                        Name = directory.Name,
                        Path = directory.FullName,
                        Items = GetItems(directory.FullName)
                    };

                    items.Add(item);
                }

                foreach (var file in dirInfo.EnumerateFiles())
                {
                    InteropBitmap thumbImg = ShellFile.FromFilePath(file.FullName).Thumbnail.BitmapSource as InteropBitmap;
                    thumbImg.Freeze();

                    var item = new FamilyItem
                    {
                        Name = file.Name,
                        Path = file.FullName,
                        FamImage = thumbImg
                    };

                    if (item.Name.Contains(".rfa"))
                    {

                    items.Add(item);

                    }

                }

                return items;
            }
            else
            {

                return items;
            }
        }
```

DirectoryItem and FamilyItem both inherits a model called Item:

**Item model:**

```
public class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public InteropBitmap FamImage { get; set; }
    }
```

**DirectoryItem model:**

```
public class DirectoryItem : Item

    {
        public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    
        public DirectoryItem()
        {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        }
    }
```

**FamilyItem:**

```
 public class FamilyItem : Item
    {

    }
```

**I'm filtering the collection with:**

```
Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>(ItemsCache.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(SearchText.ToLower())));
```

I only get the top directories that match - I want to get all the "end" files that match - how would I go about doing that?

Comment: modified the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `.Where(..)` by a recursive version:

```
   public static class ExtenstioMethods
   {
      public static IEnumerable<Item> Where<Item>(this IEnumerable<Item> source, Func<Item, bool> predicate)
      {
         var result = new List<Item>();
         foreach (var item in source)
         {
            if ((item is FamilyItem) && predicate(item))
            {
               result.Add(item);
            }
            else if (item is DirectoryItem)
            {
               var newSourc = ((item as DirectoryItem).Items) as IEnumerable<Item>;
               result = result.Union(newSourc.Where(predicate)).ToList();
            }
         }
         return result;
      }
   }
```

Comment: Okay, so this somewhat does the trick. I can search for the item names, but I'm now returning only those items. 
Is it possible to somehow not flatten the list so that is keeps the hierarchal treeview structure?

Comment: I’m accepting your answer because I’m going with this solution, sinde it is 99% what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

OK, modified the answer.
You have to flatten your collection berforehand (or collect it flattened).

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> GetItemsFlat(string path)
        {
            var items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
                return items;
            
            var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);

            foreach (var directory in dirInfo.EnumerateDirectories())
            {
                var item = new DirectoryItem
                {
                    Name = directory.Name,
                    Path = directory.FullName,
                    Items = GetItems(directory.FullName)
                };

                items.Add(item);
                foreach (var item in GetItemsFlat(directory.FullName))
                    items.Add(item);
            }

            foreach (var file in dirInfo.EnumerateFiles("*.rfa"))
            {
                InteropBitmap thumbImg = ShellFile.FromFilePath(file.FullName).Thumbnail.BitmapSource as InteropBitmap;
                thumbImg.Freeze();

                var item = new FamilyItem
                {
                    Name = file.Name,
                    Path = file.FullName,
                    FamImage = thumbImg
                };
                items.Add(item)
            }
        }
```

Use the `Path` (ie. FullName) property for filtering, to include files in matched subdirectories, ie.

`ItemsCache.Where(x => x.Path.ToLower().Contains(SearchText.ToLower()))`

also refactor Your code to use "return early" strategy. (https://dev.to/jpswade/return-early-12o5)

Ie. instead of
`if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(path)) { ...lots of code }`
do

```
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path)) return EmptyCollection;`

...lots of code
```

You could also improve this code to discard 'empty' directory subtrees from collection.

Also check `GetFileSystemInfo` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfilesysteminfos?view=net-6.0 which can be used to search files including subdirectories

Comment: What exactly is the benefit from filtering from Path versus Name? I'm still only searching the top directories, so I'm not getting the wanted behavior. 

Is refactored to return early - I was not aware that this was a common/best practice.

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer. However I'm still not sure this does what I'm after. If i flatten the list, wont I lose the hierarchy structure of the treeview?